# Flex - Argument count mismatch, expecting 0 got 1

Tags: apache-flex, button, event-handling

I created a save button and added an eventlistener to run the saveAs() when the button is clicked but I'm getting

Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on views::TxtView/saveAs(). Expected 0, got 1.

I haven't supplied any arguments.

In my init()
...

```
var saveAsFileBtn:IconButton = new IconButton();
                saveAsFileBtn.setIcon("../icons/saveas.png");
                saveAsFileBtn.width=100;
                saveAsFileBtn.x=saveFileBtn.width+71;
                saveAsFileBtn.sizeMode = SizeMode.BOTH;
                saveAsFileBtn.sizeUnit = SizeUnit.PIXELS    
                saveAsFileBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveAs);
```

...

then

```
private function saveAs():void 
            {
                trace("Save as");
                var fileChooser:File;
                if (currentFile)
                {
                    fileChooser = currentFile;
                }
                else
                {
                    fileChooser = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('untitled.html')
                }
                fileChooser.browseForSave("Save As");
                fileChooser.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveAsFileSelected);
            }
```

The debugger stops when the Save As button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method definition is incorrect.
Try : `private function saveAs(event:MouseEvent):void`

Comment: Thanks guys. Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

Flex wants the event listener to accept the MouseEvent that caused it to be called. Altering your method definition to the following should fix your problem.

```
private function saveAs(e:MouseEvent):void
```

If the method is called from any other context, you can pass a `null` as the parameter. Alternatively, you could make a small wrapper method that takes the event, and calls `saveAs()` internally.

```
saveAsFileBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveAsWrapper);
...

private function saveAsWrapper(e:MouseEvent):void  
{
    saveAs();
}
```